# How did health care work before Australia had medicare?

Tags: australia, healthcare

[Medicare](https://www.humanservices.gov.au/customer/dhs/medicare) is the Australian public healthcare system, what did Australia have before it existed.

Comment: Seems to be more on topic on History.SE, but would likely be closed there as the question  avoids even the most basic research.

Answer (score 9):

Prior to Medicare was Medibank, initiated by the Whitlam Government and one of the policies that resulted in the double dissolution. It was eventually implemented in 1974.

Prior to that, there didn't appear to be any standardised public funding (except for QLD which apparently did have a universal free health care program).

The following [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medicare_(Australia) should give you a good place to start for further research.

Comment: Worth noting also that Medibank is _now_ a private health insurer.

Comment: As of 2014, yes it is now a fully privatized entity listed on the ASX. Here's a link to the company history (https://www.medibank.com.au/about/company/overview/history/) - it's a bit like "Grandad's Axe" - the one that's had three different heads and the haft replaced four times but is still the same axe...